# How do I open Python IDLE (Shell WIndow) in WIndows 10?

Tags: python, shell

I am just starting to learn Python and I am using Windows 10. I downloaded and installed Python 3.4.3. But everytime I open Python from my Desktop or from C:\Python\python.exe it just opens a black command prompt without any Menu options like File menu, Edit Menu, Format Menu etc. I can't see any colors of the code, it's just black screen with white text. I searched about it on internet and came to know that what I am opening is the Editor winodws and I need to open Shell Window in order to have access to all of those options and features. I can't figure out where is the .exe of Shell Window and with what name is it? Please help me.

P.S. I also tried to open pythonw.exe that was present in the Python folder where it was installed, but nothing opened.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Windows you will need to right click a .py, and press Edit to edit the file using IDLE. Since the default action of double clicking a .py is executing the file with python on a shell prompt.

To open just IDLE:

Click on that. `C:\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat`

Comment: Right click on python.exe?

Comment: On the file you want to open

Comment: I want to open the IDLE (Shell Window) of Python 3.4.3

Comment: Python is python, idle is Idle, they're different things, python automatically install Idle for you.

Comment: So where is this IDLE located? I can't find it's .exe and I want to open it.

Comment: Well, the easiest way to open IDLE is to create a blank .py file, and do what I said in the answer

Comment: Or C:\Python36\Lib\idlelib\idle.bat and double click that

Comment: and how do I create the blank .py file?

Comment: Thanks, C:\Python34\Lib|idlelib\idle.bat worked for me, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

Start menu > type `IDLE (Python 3.4.3 <bitnum>-bit)`.

Replace `<bitnum>` with 32 if 32-bit, otherwise 64.

Example:

> IDLE (Python 3.6.2 64-bit)

I agree with one who says:

> just type "IDLE" in the start-menu where it says "Type here to search" and press **[**{**ENTER**}**]**

Comment: Your answer would be effectively redundant (and also overly specific) to the existing one by `K p` then.

Answer (score 2):

If your using Windows 10 just type in `idle` where it says: "Type here for search"

Comment: This does not work for me on Windows 10 with the installation that I got from the main Python website. It appears that the installation didn't register itself with the search bar results when Python 3.7 (what I have installed currently) was added to my system.

Comment: For a new install it won't find IDLE, it'll look for a Microsoft App or search the web.  The user may have to go to the python folder and look for IDLE.bat as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to setting options and then invoking Idle on a python script is:

```
Set optn=blah
...
Set optn=blah
start pythonw C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py STFxlate.py
```

This allows you to setup the environment prior to invoking idle.
This assumes that pythonw is in the current path

Comment: Egad, it runs the lines together, it should read:

My solution to setting options and then invoking Idle on a python script is:

Set optn=blah

...

Set optn=blah

start pythonw C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py STFxlate.py

This allows you to setup the environment prior to invoking idle. This assumes that pythonw is in the current path

Comment: My solution to setting options and then invoking Idle on a python script is: 

Set optn=blah 

... 

Set optn=blah 

start pythonw C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\idlelib\idle.py STFxlate.py

This allows you to setup the environment prior to invoking idle. This assumes that pythonw is in the current path

Answer (score 0):

For those using Anaconda, type idle on windows search bar ("Run or Execute command"). This probably wont work if you didn't install anaconda with environment variables. You can also go to

```
Anaconda3 folder > Scripts >idle.exe
```

and create a shortcut to you desktop.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Idle can be opened as an edit window or a shell window.
To get the the idle edit window from the shell window is very simple if you know how.
Here's how:

1. Windows search for "idle"
2. Click 'enter'
3. idle shell appears
4. click options in idle shell
5. click configure idle
6. a new window appears
7. click the 'Windows' tab
8. click 'open edit window'

> next time you open idle, the edit window will appear.